# UNIX: C: cc compiler. Command Line: How to display the binary file header on screen

Tags: c, unix, header, command

I am looking for the unix command to display the header portion in Hex for any excutable that has been compiled by the cc compiler.
I had this once and now I cant remember it. 
I just want to see what the compiler code that is at the start of any c programs that I compile

I am aware that I can use 'hexdump [filename]'  however that doesnt isolate the header portion .
Hope i have explained myself well enough.....

Comment: [Linux Binary Analysis](http://amzn.to/2scWuIv) by Ryan "elfmaster" O'Neill explains all of the intricacies of the ELF binary format used by UNIX, Linux and similar operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

The command `readelf` is available on most Linux systems and has the ability to display many parts of an ELF file.  You can use `readelf -H` to get a short synopsis of the various options.

To get just the file header you can use `readelf -h` or `readelf --fileheader` to display the file header.

To see it in hex, you can use the command `xxd`.  Given that the elf header is 64 bytes (on a 64-bit machine), you can use `xxd -l 64`

Answer (score 0):

Objdump command in Linux is used to provide thorough information on object files. This command is mainly used by the programmers who work on compilers, but still its a very handy tool for normal programmers also when it comes to debugging. In this article, we will understand how to use objdump command through some examples.

Basic syntax of objdump is :

```
objdump [options] objfile...
```

There is a wide range of options available for this command.

For example, factorial is the c program that I have to compiled.

1.Display object format specific file header contents using
 -p option

The following example prints the object file format specific information.

```
$ objdump -p factorial
```

2. Display the contents of all headers using -x option

Information related to all the headers in the object file can be retrieved using the -x option.

```
objdump -x factorial
```